# Making comments stand out when using Sweave and R

Tags: highlighting, sweave

Is there any way to bold or highlight all comments when using Sweave? Maybe a command to make all lines starting with `#` be bolded?

```
<<>>=
# I want this to be bold automatically
@
```

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine `\hlcom` command.

```
% !Rnw weave = knitr
% !TeX program = pdfLaTeX

\documentclass[final,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\hlcom}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.678,0.584,0.686}{\textbf{#1}}}%

\begin{document}
<<>>=
  # commented text
@
\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image: result]

Comment: ! LaTeX Error: \hlcom undefined.

Comment: I'm using Sweave and not knitr. Is that the problem? (Would switching over be easy?)

Comment: @EarlBellinger It should be easy and you definitely should switch: http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/sweave/ (Disclaimer: I'm the knitr author, so I'm biased by definition)